# I can't figure out how to make a function to catch keyboard shortcuts correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

When I hold down a modifier key (shift, ctrl, alt), I need to press the second key very quickly, otherwise I get, for example, shift + shift. and the second problem: if I just click on the same shift, I also get shift + shift

```
def hotkey(widget):
    key = keyboard.read_key()
    modificator = ["shift", "ctrl", "alt"]
    if keyboard.is_pressed(modificator[0]):
        modkey = keyboard.read_key()
        key = modificator[0] + " + " + modkey
    elif keyboard.is_pressed(modificator[1]):
        modkey = keyboard.read_key()
        key = modificator[1] + " + " + modkey
    elif keyboard.is_pressed(modificator[2]):
        modkey = keyboard.read_key()
        key = modificator[2] + " + " + modkey
    widget.value = key.title()
    widget.update()
    print(key)
```

I need it to wait as long as necessary for the second key when holding down the modifier key, and so that when you click on the modifier, it returns only the key.
Sorry for my english if i wrote something wrongy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a (fairly complex) code that should do what you want. It should catch all <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Key</kbd> combinations.

```py
# Import the keyboard module
import keyboard

# Define a list of modifier keys
modifiers = ["ctrl", "alt", "shift"]

# Initialize the modifier variable as None
modifier = None

# Define a function to handle key press events
def on_press(event):
    # Get the name of the pressed key
    key = event.name

    # Check if the key is a modifier key
    if key in modifiers:
        # Set the global variable to store the modifier key
        global modifier
        modifier = key
    else:
        # Check if there is a modifier key stored
        if modifier:
            # Print the shortcut combination
            print(modifier + "+" + key)
            # Reset the modifier variable
            modifier = None

# Define a function to handle key release events
def on_release(event):
    # Get the name of the released key
    key = event.name

    # Check if the key is a modifier key
    if key in modifiers:
        # Check if there is no other modifier key pressed
        if not any(keyboard.is_pressed(m) for m in modifiers):
            # Print the modifier key alone
            print(key)
            # Reset the modifier variable
            global modifier
            modifier = None

# Hook the functions to the keyboard events
keyboard.on_press(on_press)
keyboard.on_release(on_release)

# Wait for the user to press Esc to exit
keyboard.wait("esc")
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not a native python developer but this code should work, if there are any questions just ask :)  :

```
import keyboard

def hotkey(widget):
    modificator = ["shift", "ctrl", "alt"]
    key=""
    modkey = ""
    while key not in modificator:
        key = keyboard.read_key()
        print(f"1. {key}") 
    while modkey in modificator or modkey == "":
        modkey = keyboard.read_key()
    #widget.value = key.title()
    #widget.update()
    print(f"{key} + {modkey}")
```

Comment: in this case, there are also problems when I just click on the modifier (press and release), the program also waits for me to press another key